# How show keyboard language icon in the top?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-desktop

Windows 10 (64 bit)

In my system tray I has keyboard language icon.

[image]

OK. But I want to show language icon in the top of screen. How I can do this?
I windows 7 I do this, but on Windows 10 I don't know how I can do this.

Comment: What are you doing on Windows 7 that is no longer working on Windows 10?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT It's was long time ago. I don't remember what I can did on Windows 7.

Comment: If this isn't a question about programming, it's off-topic for StackOverflow, sorry.